# ejQuery function for keyCode and slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do you know why my function works just for one click on my keyboard ?
I would like to move my slider with using right and left arrow.
Right arrow works just one time. I'd like to add left arrow too, in my function...
HTML

```
<div class="container slider">
    <ul>
        <li id="slider"><img src="img/slider/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li id="slider2"><img src="img/slider/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li id="slider3"><img src="img/slider/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li id="slider4"><img src="img/slider/4.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
.slideshow {
  height: 700px;
  background: #676767;
}

.slider {
  width: 960px;
  height: 420px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider ul {
  width: 200%;
  height: 420px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.slider li {
  float: left;
}

.slider img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {

    var keyCodeL = 39;
    var keyCodeR = 37;

    $('body').keypress(function(){
        if(keyCodeL === 39){
            $('#slider').animate({'margin-left': -980},800)
        }else if (keyCodeR === 37){
            $('#slider2').animate({'margin-left': -1960 },800)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: your if statements are always true

Answer (score 0):

You are logically wrong. Conditions should check with key pressed. You are checking the values against their own values. For ex :

```
 if(keyCodeL === 39){
```

is always true because you declared on top that  `var keyCodeL = 39;`

You need to check, which key pressed

```
$('body').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === keyCodeL ){
            $('#slider').animate({'margin-left': -980},800)
        }else if (e.keyCode ===keyCodeR){
            $('#slider2').animate({'margin-left': -1960 },800)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Oh well i see ! Thank you very much !
Now i need to find how to move my slider (four images) with right and left arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is incorrect. Instead of checking for the current key pressed, instead you are checking the values of the variables namely `keycodeL, keycodeR`

You should rewirite the if conditions and also I would like to mention that use `$(document)` rather than `$(body)`

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.charCode == keycodeL){
    //Code for left arrow
    }
    else if(event.charCode == keycodeR){
    //Code for right arrow 
    }
    });
```